# Minio CURLE_PEER_FAILED_VERIFICATION

Tags: curl, minio

I have opened a forum post in virtualmin, because I told that my Issue is related to their software, but seems the problem comes from MINIO.
They said "Probably best to ask within the minio community", but I can't find minio forum and my minio is installed on Truenas as a plugin I will try it here.

So. I have a web server with wordpress installed on virtualmin and I have a plugin for Wordpress called "Media Cloud" witch allowed me to offload my media to amazon S3 or in my case MINIO. The problem is that my MINIO have self signed Certificate and when this plugin is trying to connect to MINIO I am getting cURL Error 60:

```
CURLE_PEER_FAILED_VERIFICATION (60) The remote server's SSL certificate or SSH md5 fingerprint was deemed not OK. This error code has been unified with CURLE_SSL_CACERT since 7.62.0. Its previous value was 51
```

I can use `-k --insecure` to bypass curl, but is there a way to make my web server trust the self signed certificate of my minio server?

The last answer of a user from the Virtualmin Forum was:

> In the past I have had to import the certificate .pem and .key file to
> the server for a service I used (not minio). It's app specific and the
> process depends on the service. Some will use their own portals whilst
> others require you to manually copy across. Probably best to ask
> within the minio community of people who have done this themselves
> with the self generated certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your webserver to trust the self-signed certificate you are using in MinIO, you need to add it your system's trusted certificate store. The process to do this varies by the kind of system you have - for e.g. on Ubuntu Linux: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-trust-store

Once you add this your webserver should accept the certificate provided by MinIO and not return this error.

With regards to the MinIO forum, if you have further MinIO support related questions, please know you can find us at https://slack.min.io/ 24/7/365. If you have commercial questions, please reach out to us on hello@min.io or on our Ask an Expert Chat functionality at https://min.io/pricing?action=talk-to-us.